# How to route traffic from Azure App gateway to Istio?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, istio

Am trying Istio and have basic requirement.

I know Istio cannot be linked with Azure App Gateway but what i know is both istio & app gateway can stay together (based on this [How to configure Azure App Gateway in Istio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113682/how-to-configure-azure-app-gateway-in-istio))

I have very basic issue. When i try to hit application using app gateway IP, I am getting request in Nginx but then it fails due to istio. In Nginx deployment, I added keys in annotations but no luck.

```
annotations:
sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts: 80,443
traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts: ""
```

**Edit**: (Adding more info)
Was able to take this further with sample echo-server code and was able to access the webpage. But when I change the service to Nginx (Nginx will redirect to nodejs for auth), nothing renders.

Only error I get is "HTTP ERROR 426"

Code for echo-server

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: echo-server
    labels:
        app: echo-server
spec:
    ports:
        - name: http
          port: 80
          targetPort: 8080
    selector:
        app: echo-server
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: echo-server
    labels:
        app: echo-server
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: echo-server
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: echo-server
        spec:
            containers:
                -
                    image: "inanimate/echo-server"
                    imagePullPolicy: Always
                    name: echo-server
                    ports:
                        -
                            containerPort: 8080
                    livenessProbe:
                        httpGet:
                            path: /
                            port: 8080
                    readinessProbe:
                        httpGet:
                            path: /       
                            port: 8080 
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: echo-server
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - echo-server
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 80
        host: echo-server.default.svc.cluster.local
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: echo-server
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: AUTO_PASSTHROUGH
    hosts:
    - "*"
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: echo-server
  annotations:
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - myapp.123456.com
      secretName: my-tls
  rules:
  - host: myapp.123456.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: istio-ingressgateway
          servicePort: 80
```

Any help how can I fix this?

Comment: Your setup looks fine. The problem you are facing probably has to do with the fact that, by default, Nginx still uses HTTP/1.0 for upstream connections, and AFAIK, Envoy proxy, used internally by Istio, does not support HTTP/1.0. This is the reason why is returning a `426` HTTP error code, `Upgrade required`. Try to force Nginx to use HTTP/1.1 for upstream connections. I do not know in your concrete setup, but you can, for instance, configuring `proxy_http_version 1.1` in the server configuration file.